# uninitialized constant [Incident::Involf]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have a rails app that is using Active Admin. Basic flow is that I have an Incident model has associations with other models. Connections other models seem fine but for one model (Involves) in particular I get the error uninitialized constant Incident::Involf when creating a new Incident.

Incident model looks like this

```
class Incident < ActiveRecord::Base
 # Relationships
 belongs_to :admin_user
 has_many :images
 has_and_belongs_to_many :incident_types
 has_and_belongs_to_many :involves
 has_and_belongs_to_many :special_considerations

 belongs_to :county
 belongs_to :location


 # Nested Attributes
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :county
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :location
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :incident_types
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :involves
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :special_considerations   
end
```

The Involve model looks like this

```
class Involve < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Relationships
  has_and_belongs_to_many :incidents

  # Aliases
  alias_attribute :name, :involved

end
```

The active admin model for nested Incidents look like this

```
f.inputs "Vehicles Involved" do
    f.input :involves, :as => :check_boxes
 end

f.inputs "Special Considerations" do
    f.input :special_considerations, :as => :check_boxes
end
```

Where Special Considerations work if I have f.input :involves, :as => :check_boxes commented out, but I get this error if I don't have it commented out.

Looked at the database and the associations and the code is very similar to others that I am not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved.

It looked liked to be an issue with either the pluralization of Involve or involve is a keyword.

I changed the model name to Incident_Involvement and that resolved the issue.